# Python: Requests patch method doesn't work

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have the code below which works fine and brings back what I need

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
response = requests.get('https://example/answers/331', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'),json={"solution": "12345"})
print response.content
```

However when I change it to a `patch` method, which is accepted by the server, I get the following errors. Any idea on why?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auth.py", line 8, in <module>
    response = requests.patch('https://example/answers/331', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'),json={"solution": "12345"})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 138, in patch
    return request('patch', url,  data=data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.12.0-py2.7.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 473, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

Thanks

Comment: That's a server issue, not a `requests` issue. Your server response is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a POST request with the following header: X-HTTP-Method-Override: PATCH
This is unique to the Oracle Service Cloud REST API implementation and [is documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/servicecs_gs/CXSVC/Chunk116776251.html#aa1151348).

Comment: I have tried but no go - will do some more testing today just to be on the safe side

Answer (score 0):

In cases where the browser or client application does not support PATCH requests, or network intermediaries block PATCH requests, HTTP tunneling can be used with a POST request by supplying an X-HTTP-Method-Override header.

Example:

```
import requests

restURL = <Your REST URL>
params = {'field': 'val'}
headers = {'X-HTTP-Method-Override':'PATCH'}
try:
    resp = requests.post(restURL, json=params, auth=('<uname>', '<pwd>'), headers=headers)
    print resp
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    errMsg = "Error: %s" % err  
    print errMsg
```